# Problem in Reading Data from CSV file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am facing an issue while reading the data from CSV file to pass the values to the request. I have a csv with 3 columns userid, password and type.When the data is being passed for the username field, its taking the values of 3 columns instead of just the username
Jmeter version: 5.0

CSV file value:

[image]
[image]

Can you please help me if i am doing it wrong.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Double check the "Delimiter" in your CSV file because if it's different from the default comma `,` you will need to change it accordingly:

[image]

In order to be 100% sure in the test data integrity I would recommend opening it with a text editor like [Notepad](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-notepad/9msmlrh6lzf3) instead of Excel as JMeter treats CSV files as plain text and this is you should be also doing when validating your test data.

You may find [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) useful for visualising [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are generated by CSV Data Set Config, Post-Processors and some [pre-defined variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars).

Answer (score 0):

Let me see the variable you insert into the Login request. Everything is find with your config. Maybe it about your CSV file. Please sure format of CSV file when you open with Notepad not Microsoft Word like this

```
userid,password,type
test@test.com,Test@123,Vehicle
test@test.com,Test@123,Vehicle
test@test.com,Test@123,Vehicle
```